# Javascript nodejs & arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

Basically I've been failing to create an array the way i want it, What do you think is the best method to create an array to output ALL regexp Matches that are found? Could you show me an example?

Here's an example of the output: which is passed from a variable called msg

> id name ping snap updt posi dist
>
> 765611981281#### nameexampple1 600 0 0
>
> 765611981281#### nameexampple2 31 0 0
>
> 765611981281#### nameexampple3 41 0 0

Basically I want to match and output captures to array so only the ID/Name/Ping lines are indexed each on their own inside an array index that I can call later with the regex group like arraylist[2].highping[2] and that would output (nameexample2 because its the arraylist 2nd line) as highping regex group 2 is the username for that capture.

```
//RegExp
var pingchecker = new RegExp(/^([0-9]{0,17}).+?(\w+).+?([0-9].+).+?([0-9]).+?([0-9])/m); //set to multi line
 
//Finds RegExp of id name ping etc from msg which is the live feed to rcon
if (/^id.+?name.+?ping.+?snap.+?updt.+?posi.+?dist/.test(msg)) {
  console.log('PING CHECKER - Passing to Conditional');
 
//Finds RegExp of pingchecker from msg which is the live feed to rcon
  if((highping = pingchecker.exec(msg))) {
    console.log('SteamID: ' + highping[1] + ' PlayerName: ' + highping[2] + ' Ping: ' + highping[3]) //outputs one player as normal.
  }
  
}
```

Does this make sense to anyone? Am I going about this wrong? Basically i need pointers, above code is only output of the first found match for example.

Comment: I guess you can improve your question by hand constructing the expected array output. Describing it in pure text can be confusing.

Comment: yes, an example of expected output goes a long way to help

Comment: Thanks for comments, but seems someone already solved my problem for me already. Thanks for your replies ill take that into account next time I post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I *think* you are looking for something like the following code.  It will put each match array into an array of matches so you can "can call later with the regex group".

Changes:

1. Change the `pingchecker` RegExp to [match globally using `/g`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#Parameters).  This allows it to match more than just once in the string.
2. Change `if` to [`while` so it loops through finding all matches](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec#Finding_successive_matches) instead of just the first one.
3. Add variable `resultArray` to hold the results so, as requested in the question, "output captures to array" so you can "can call later with the regex group".
4. Move `console.log()` into a separate [`resultsArray.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) loop to demonstrate that the `resultsArray` has been populated.

```js
var msg= `id name ping snap updt posi dist

765611981281#### nameexampple1 600 0 0

765611981281#### nameexampple2 31 0 0

765611981281#### nameexampple3 41 0 0`;
    
//RegExp (multi line and global)
var pingchecker = new RegExp(/^([0-9]{0,17}).+?(\w+).+?([0-9].+).+?([0-9]).+?([0-9])/mg);
var resultArray =[];

//Finds RegExp of id name ping etc from msg which is the live feed to rcon
if (/^id.+?name.+?ping.+?snap.+?updt.+?posi.+?dist/.test(msg)) {
    console.log('PING CHECKER - Passing to Conditional');

    //Finds RegExp of pingchecker from msg which is the live feed to rcon
    //Loop through all matches, adding them to the OP requested resultsArray
    while(highping = pingchecker.exec(msg)) {
        resultArray.push(highping);
    }
}

//Loop through resultsArray and output the matches
resultArray.forEach(function(result){
     //output player
    console.log('SteamID: ' + result[1] + ' PlayerName: ' + result[2] 
                + ' Ping: ' + result[3]);
});
```

Comment: Explain what you changed and why.

Comment: @Makyen It is not a good idea to remove start assertion character from the first regex, because it may match a wrong message. And better use template literals for `msg`.

Comment: @SoftwareEngineer171, You are correct.  That was left from the first pass at self-creating the `msg` variable.  When I went back and put in the newlines in that variable, I did not change that back.  I agree that it is desirable to match after the newline.

Comment: @SoftwareEngineer171, I initially did not use a template literal due to not previously trying it with StackOverflow Snippets.  It initially looked quite strange to have the template literal where I was attempting to match the beginning of a line `^` but having excess space characters at the beginning of the line. I did initially try it, but it did not appear to work.  I must have typed something wrong initially, because when I went back and put it back, it worked fine. That was also the reason the `^` initially was removed.

Comment: Thank you all for taking each of your time to help solve this, I was WAY overthinking my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to repeat executing regex until you reach the last player. Replace `if` with `while` (otherwise you'll get only the first player). Also, you need to add global regex modifier at your `pingchecker`.

```
var msg = `id name ping snap updt posi dist

765611981281#### nameexampple1 600 0 0

765611981281#### nameexampple2 31 0 0

765611981281#### nameexampple3 41 0 0`;

//RegExp
var pingchecker = new RegExp(/^([0-9]{0,17}).+?(\w+).+?([0-9].+).+?([0-9]).+?([0-9])/mg); //set to multi line

//Finds RegExp of id name ping etc from msg which is the live feed to rcon
if (/^id.+?name.+?ping.+?snap.+?updt.+?posi.+?dist/.test(msg)) {
  console.log('PING CHECKER - Passing to Conditional');


//Finds RegExp of pingchecker from msg which is the live feed to rcon
  while((highping = pingchecker.exec(msg))) {
    console.log('SteamID: ' + highping[1] + ' PlayerName: ' + highping[2] + ' Ping: ' + highping[3]) //outputs one player as normal.
  }

}
```